# SQLSTATE 42S22 Column not found

Tags: laravel-5

I know that I don't have the table in phpmyadmin
but the problem is I don't know how to do it the right way

The code

```
    public function DriverRefer($id)
{
    $driver = Driver::find($id);
    $query = ReferralDiscount::where([['referral_driver_id', '=', $id], ['referral_sender_id', '!=', 0]])->latest();
    $referral_details = $query->paginate(25);
    return view('merchant.driver.driver_refer', compact('referral_details', 'driver'));
}
```

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S22)
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'referral_driver_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `referral_discounts` where (`referral_driver_id` = 4130 and `referral_sender_id` != 0))
>   Previous exceptions
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'referral_driver_id' in 'where clause' (42S22)

Answer (score 0):

I added a model inside App/Models named `DriverReferralDiscount`:

```
<?php

class DriverReferralDiscount extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function Driver()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Driver::class, 'referral_driver_id');
    }

    public function SenderDriver()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Driver::class, 'referral_sender_id');
    }

    public function getSenderDetails($driver_id)
    {
        $refer = ReferralDiscount::where([['referral_driver_id', '=', $driver_id], ['referral_sender_id', '!=', 0]])->get();
        return $refer;
    }

    public function getSenderCount($driver_id)
    {
        $refer = ReferralDiscount::where([['referral_driver_id', '=', $driver_id], ['referral_sender_id', '!=', 0]])->count();
        return $refer;
    }}
```

And changed the code to

```
public function DriverRefer($id){
$driver = Driver::find($id);
$query = DriverReferralDiscount::where([['referral_driver_id', '=', $id], ['referral_sender_id', '!=', 0]])->latest();
$referral_details = $query->paginate(25);
return view('merchant.driver.driver_refer', compact('referral_details', 'driver'));}
```

Then i added a table in phpmyadmin named `driver_referral_discounts` with columns:

```
id  
referral_driver_id  
referral_sender_id  
referral_offer  
referral_offer_value    
referral_available  
created_at  
updated_at
```

Really sorry if it's not clear but i tried as best as i could in case this would help anyone else.